# ImportXML function in Google Sheets produces error 'Imported content is empty' Error

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, finance

I am trying to use the ImportXML formula in Google Sheet to pull some Analyst rating data from Stock Target Advisor. Here is the formula that I am using for pulling Avg. Target Price:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.stocktargetadvisor.com/stock/Asia/NSE/PETRONET#analyst-rating-tab","/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/span/span")
```

I am also trying to use similar other data points from this website by using the Copy XPath in Inspect Element as given below, but getting the same error in each instance.

**Xpaths**

Analyst
/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a

Rating
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p

Target Price
/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]

Target Date
/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]

Avg. Target Price
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/span/span

Avg. Analyst Rating
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p

Fundamental Analysis
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/p

Some help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can safely scrape only this:

[image]

rest is JS controlled and import functions of google sheets are not capable of reading such elements

Comment: Yeah figured out the same myself after a while, seems like something they should add